# Add two ranges and use the result as an IF condition Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Please help me with this. I am trying to have an if condition where the condition is taken from the result of two added ranges then if the result is greater than 31 then the exceeding amount would add up to another cell.

Example:
`IF (A1:A5 + B1:B5) > 31 Then`

`Value = C1:C5 + 5` *so the additional value for column C would be +5 if the value of `A1 + B1` is 36.

End if

As of now this is what I got:

```
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Worksheets("Project Planner").Range("C6:C16")
  If cell.Value > 31 Then
    Worksheets("Database").Range("D6:D16").Value = cell.Value + 31
  End If
Next
```

I don't know how to add two ranges and use the result as my condition. I am new to VBA, any help would be appreciated. TIA!

Comment: your question statement is not clear, could you please rewrite and then I can help

Comment: Hi, sure I'll rewrite my question to make it clear, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your your loop works, you will have to use different criteria for how you display the values you are adding.

Using a for loop, rather than a for each loop, I would be able to say that my If criteria has the sum of cells in the row i for columns 2 and 4 is greater than 31 by coding:

```
For i = 6 to 16
    If (Cells(i, 2).Value + Cells(i, 4).Value) > 31 Then
        'Function
    End If
Next i
```

Given your for each loop, you can use offset() to help show this same use of columns 2 (B) and 4 (D), such as:

```
For Each cell in Worksheets("Project Planner").Range("C6:C16")
    If (cell.Offset(0,-1).Value + cell.Offset(0,1).Value) > 31 Then
        'Function
    End If
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rng1, rng2, rng3 As Range
Set rng1 = Worksheets("Project Planner").Range("C6:C16")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Project Planner").Range("D6:D16")
Set rng3 = Worksheets("Project Planner").Range("E6:E16")

For i = 1 to rng1.rows.count
  if rng1.cells(i,1) + rng2.cells(i,1) > 31 then
    rng3.cells(i,1) = rng3.cells(i,1) + (rng1.cells(i,1)+rng2.cells(i,1)-31)
  end if
next i
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to implement this, so i pasted it on my module and tried to run it as a macro and I get a Run-time error '424': Object required.

Comment: I see. there was an error in the line  "For i = 1....". I corrected it now. Try it out